# How to sort textbooks by type by color code, or category in bookweb using html, Javascript, CSS or other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am currently trying to sort a textbook list that is generated dynamically by bookweb (a bookshop cart solution). I want to order the cart by the textbook type either prescribed or recommended. Currently that information is served in a type field by the cart problem is we can't edit the carts cgi files to sort them like that. So primary sort is by subjects, a student can enter up to 4, secondary sort is by textbook type either prescribed or recommended sorted in that order. The format it is in currently, is as follows:

```
Title             Type          Author           ISBN                Price

Subject Name      
Textbooks         Prescribed    xxxx             xxxx                xxx
Textbooks         Recommended   xxxx             xxxx                xxx

Subject Name....//it then repeats for all subjects entered
```

What I need is:

```
Title          Author           ISBN                Price

Subject Name 
Prescribed     
 Textbooks     xxxxx            xxxx                xxx
Recommended 
 Textbooks     xxxxx            xxxx                xxx

Subject Name....//it then repeats for all subjects entered
```

I have tried using Javascript and CSS to color code the books depending on the type, but it only does the first row and only prescribed:

```
if (<BOOKWEB-TYPE> == "Prescribed"){
  //alert("prescribed");
  document.getElementById("textbook").className = "bsPrescribed";
}
else if (<BOOKWEB-TYPE> == "Recommended"){
  //alert("recommended");
  document.getElementById("textbook").className = "bsRecommended";
}
```

I put in the alerts for troubleshooting and even then only the alert for prescribed comes up even though there are recommended books in the list. I have also tried getElementsByName but that didn't work at all. Even if it did though I would still have mixed colors since it wouldn't be sorting to the books by those two categories (prescribed or recommended) which is preferred.

What is the fastest, easiest way to achieve this.

**Update1:**

Now the getElementById isn't even highlighting the first row, it did change the class but the CSS never took effect. Now even the class doesn't change.

**Update2:**

Oops I mistyped that here, fixed it and checked the code swell its fine, but now it just doesn't run that script at all, with further messing around I realised that I needed quotation marks around `<BOOKWEB-TYPE>` so:

```
if ("<BOOKWEB-TYPE>" == "Prescribed"){
  alert("prescribed");
  document.getElementById("textbook").className = "bsPrescribed";
}

else if ("<BOOKWEB-TYPE>" == "Recommended"){
  alert("recommended");
  document.getElementById("textbook").className = "bsRecommended";
}
```

But now what it does is it only updates the first line of the and colors it green when the prescribed books are reached and yellow when the recommended books are reached (as per defined CSS clases) but it doesn't change the class of any other books after the first line. The alerts display fine though as they should, so I know its differentiating prescribed from recommended.

**Update 3:**

Tried this and now even the highlighting doesn't work as in class doesn't change. I thought the same id's would be a problem.

```
if ("<BOOKWEB-TYPE>" == "Prescribed"){
  alert("prescribed");
  document.getElementsByName("textbook").className = "bsPrescribed";
}
else if ("<BOOKWEB-TYPE>" == "Recommended"){
  alert("recommended");
  document.getElementsByName("textbook").className = "bsRecommended";
}
```

**Update 4:**
The HTML code for the textbook row:

```
<tr name="textbook" id="textbook" valign=top>
<td align=center valign=top class="bntablerow"><input type="checkbox" name="<BOOKWEB-APN>" /></td>
<td id="bntable" class="bntablerow"><a href="<BOOKWEB-BINHREF>details<BOOKWEB-CGIEXT>?ITEMNO=<BOOKWEB-APN>"><BOOKWEB-TITLE></a></td>
<td class="bntablerow"><BOOKWEB-TYPE>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="bntablerow"><BOOKWEB-AUTHOR>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="bntablerow"><BOOKWEB-ISBN>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right" class="bntablerow">$<BOOKWEB-PRICE></td>
```

**Update 5:**
So I changed the code to:

```
 var myTR = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i=0;i<myTR.length;i++) {
    if ("<BOOKWEB-TYPE>" == "Prescribed") {
      myTR[i].className = 'bsPrescribed';
    }
  }
```

This colors the prescribed and leaves the recommended uncolored which is alright but the problem is it only works for one subject at a time if you have two or three subjects  it then colors all the rows. Any ideas?

Comment: `if (<BOOKWEB-TYPE> = "Prescribed")` you are not checking, you trying to assign value. Change to `if (<BOOKWEB-TYPE> == "Prescribed")`

Comment: check update 2 in question

Answer (score 0):

As @Morpheus has mentioned the `=` is an assignment operator. You are therefore assigning `<BOOKWEB-TYPE>` the value `Prescribed` as opposed to checking if it contains that value.

You should be using the comparison operator `==` or `===`.

Some [more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Thanks for that I knew it but mistyped it. Check update 2 in code please.

Comment: Check the more information link that I sent. What you're attempting to do is check that the value contained in the variable `<BOOKWEB-TYPE>` contains the value `Prescribed` am I correct? If this is the case, what you need to do is extract the value from `<BOOKWEB-TYPE>`, assign it to a variable and then compare it. What you're currently doing will never match, i.e. the conditional statement will never return `true`

Comment: it does check the value and return true or false accordingly what it doesn't currently do is change the class of the row element <tr> which has id ="textbook" and name ="textbook", it only changed the first occurrence of it. So if it was prescribed, prescribed, recommended, prescribed, it would be green, green, yellow, green on the first line. instead of green, green, yellow, green for each line respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName()` selects all elements with name `textbook` in your case. You need to use `getElementById()` to get one element and style it, but it's ID has to be unique. Give unique ID's to your elements and you should be sorted.

Comment: That's definitely what I thought the problem was with the highlighting, but how would I create the id dynamically since the book creation is dynamic. Currently the tr code is `<tr name="textbook" id="textbook" valign=top><!--BOOK DETAILS ARE HERE--></tr>`. Check update 4

Comment: So each `tr` has same id and name? Can you change to use class instead of id? Like this `<tr name="textbook" class="textbook" valign=top>`